# Can I expect certain STL function implementations to be auto-vectorizable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, visual-studio-2017

Of course this won't apply to all methods, but for something like `std::min_element` with a `std::vector<char>`, should I expect the implementation to be auto-vectorizable?

`std::fill` would be an even more straightforward example but I suspect it simply does a `memset` or something.

Second, how can I check when the STL calls end up being auto vectorized with Visual Studio 2017? I can pass `/qvec-report:2` which tells me about my own loops and so on but it doesn't say anything about STL functions.

Comment: What do you mean by 'vectorizable'?

Comment: No, you should never expect auto vectorization and should not rely on compiler optimizations in general. Typically you should make sure that you are solving the right problem, check that you are using suitable algorithms and only then maybe check whether compiler-generated code is good enough and improve it with some hand-written intrin or assembly or other workarounds.

Comment: AFAIK `/qvec-report:2` also tells about STL function, at least I have seen the reports coming from STL (of course only for the functions you actually instantiate, i.e. use). But might depend on the MSVC version.

Comment: Intel has [opt-in support](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-improved-stdvalarray-with-intelr-c-compiler) for a version of [valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) that is passed to their [IPP library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) (Integrated Performance Primitives API)

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with C++17 there are parallel versions of many of the standard library algorithms. You call the parallel version with `std::execution::par` or `std::execution::par_unseq` as the first argument. `std::execution::par_unseq` permits (but doesn't require) vectorization.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = /* whatever */
    auto res = std::min_element(std::execution::par_unseq, vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return 0;
}
```